# Auto Complete list not displayed while automating using QTP

Tags: qtp, pega

I am trying to automate web application built using `PEGA 7` with `UFT 12.0`. There is one auto-complete dropbox, when start typing country name it will display list of options. During recording I was able to see the list and select. But while playing back, the list is not showing. 
Please let me know how to achieve this.

```
<code> Browser("Pega7").Page("CPMInteractionPortal").Frame("PegaGadget1Ifr").WebEdit("$PpyWorkPage$pCallBackDetails$_4").Set "Ind"
wait 5
Browser("Pega7").Page("CPMInteractionPortal").Frame("PegaGadget1Ifr").WebEdit("$PpyWorkPage$pCallBackDetails$_4").Set "India"
Browser("Pega 7").Page("CPMInteractionPortal").Frame("PegaGadget1Ifr").WebButton("Save").Click
Browser("Pega 7").CloseAllTabs
</code>
```

Comment: Try `WshShell.SendKeys` instead of simple `.Set`. Seems like event is not getting fired after `.Set`.

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked on PEGA application but I have worked Web applications.

Generally the textbox which are associated or generate dynamic search results depending upon the content that are typed in it, are associated with some event of the textbox like onkeydown which is triggered when any key is pressed when focus is on textbox or onkeyup when the key is released when the focus is on textbox

When this events are triggered a background ajax call is made and results are populated for you dynamically.

With QTP set methods generally it sets the value of the textbox in which the events associated to the control are not triggered.

In order to trigger those events you can use below methods(whichever is helpful for you, you can try using it)

*1. Try just clicking the textbox again, sometimes this also do the trick in some applications*

```
Browser("Pega7").Page("CPMInteractionPortal").Frame("PegaGadget1Ifr").WebEdit("$PpyWorkPage$pCallBackDetails$_4").Set "India"
Browser("Pega7").Page("CPMInteractionPortal").Frame("PegaGadget1Ifr").WebEdit("$PpyWorkPage$pCallBackDetails$_4").Click
```

*2. You can try using the FireEvent method in QTP*

```
Browser("Pega7").Page("CPMInteractionPortal").Frame("PegaGadget1Ifr").WebEdit("$PpyWorkPage$pCallBackDetails$_4").Set "India"
Browser("Pega7").Page("CPMInteractionPortal").Frame("PegaGadget1Ifr").WebEdit("$PpyWorkPage$pCallBackDetails$_4").FireEvent "onclick"
```

Note - Do try other events like onkeydown, onkeyup,onkeypress,onblur etc

*3. You can use the Sendkeys(as mentioned in your comments) for which you will have to create a shell object first
Example*

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Browser("Pega7").Page("CPMInteractionPortal").Frame("PegaGadget1Ifr").WebEdit("$PpyWorkPage$pCallBackDetails$_4").Set "India"
WshShell.SendKeys ""
```

Note - you can also type the text instead of blank in sendkeys

Let us know if nothing works, we can try finding other solutions.

Comment: You may also want to look at : http://www.knowledgeinbox.com/articles/qtp/settings/when-to-change-qtp-web-replaytype-setting/

Comment: @Aditya Any luck with above solutions?